# DLL project on Windows: Unresolved External Symbol

Tags: c++, windows, dll, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating a DLL project with Visual Studio 2012 with the intent of calling the functions from a Delphi project. I've already turned off C++ name mangling by wrapping my functions in extern "C" { /* ... */ } but to avoid the C name decoration, I'm using a DEF file.

Here's a snippet of code describing how I have things laid out:

```
// MyFile.h

#ifdef MYPROJECT_EXPORTS
#define MYPROJECT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYPROJECT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" {
    extern MYPROJECT_API void __stdcall do_something();
}
```

The .cpp file is equivalently structured. Everything matches fine.

I added a .def file to my project folder containing the following content:

```
LIBRARY MyProject
EXPORTS
    do_something=_do_something@0
```

When I build my project, everything works okay. However when I add the linker option

```
/DEFS:MyProject.def
```

I start getting errors regarding unresolved external symbols. Has anybody had this kind of issue before? I'm not new to either C++ or C but this is my first time building a DLL on Windows, as I'm primarily a Unix developer. My hypothesis is that I'm either misunderstanding or misusing the __declspec decorator, as it only breaks when I link in the def file: when I remove that flag from the linker options it builds cleanly, except with C-style decorated symbols.

EDIT: Thanks for the comments everyone, but I've gotten myself figured out now. My issue came from the fact that I was using the def file during the linking phase during creation of my DLL. I need to use the def file when using the DLL, not creating it, and everything is peachy.

Comment: I guess the linker doesn't find `_do_something@0`. Have you tried leaving just `do_something` or `do_something=do_something` in your EXPORTS section (instead of `=_do_something@0`)?

Comment: I believe you want to use the .DEF file or the __declspec, but not both.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong.  Then again, we can't see the linker errors.  Don't make us guess at them.

Comment: It turns out I was confused about what was going on where. I don't need to use the def file when linking the actual DLL, but when using it from Delphi.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments everyone, but I've gotten myself figured out now. My issue came from the fact that I was using the def file during the linking phase during creation of my DLL. I need to use the def file when using the DLL, not creating it, and everything is peachy.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all, in fact it contradicts what MSDN says.

Comment: It makes sense that now my project builds and links without issue. I'm no expert on MS technologies, but it works now, and it didn't work before. I'm not touching it nor questioning it.

Comment: I guess you don't fix what's broken, but still I can't believe the linker is not complaining when your app doesn't contain the DLL functions to be exported. (Then again, I never use the `LIBRARY` command in my def files)

Comment: It does contain the dll functions to be exported. The issue I had was when actually building my dll, it was using the .def file. What I needed to do was supply the .def file *with* my dll.

Comment: I know, what I am saying is that it's the other way around for me. I have to use the def file when building the DLL, and am unable to use it when linking to the DLL.